# uninstall.sh not in apache-net.beans16 directory installation

Tags: bash, debian, netbeans-16

Scenario:

I have installed netbeans 16 IDE on Debian 10 and now I want to remove it, but in the installation directory uninstall.sh is not present. Notice I have installed netbeans 16 trought .deb package downloaded by official netbeans site.

I tried to look for uninstall.sh script:

sudo find /netbens_directory_installation -name uninstall.sh

but no match found.

In the readme file and documentation is written that it exists and it is necessary to uninstall netbeans 16, but I don't find it.

Comment: If you installed with `dpkg`, also use `dpkg` to remove. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195794/how-to-uninstall-a-deb-installed-with-dpkg or https://askubuntu.com/questions/22200/how-to-uninstall-a-deb-package

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to solve with a few commands:

```
dpkg -l *pache-netb*
```

This command will show packages installed with the `dpkg` tool

Then, you get the name of the package you want to remove. In my case "apache.netbeans". Now you run the last command:

```
dpkg -P netbeans
```

And now IDE Netbeans 16 doesn't exist anymore.